# Python convert ctime to days since access

Tags: python-3.7, ctime

I have a file access time in the ctime format - but what I really need is the days since the file was last accessed.  How do I convert my ctime date to days since last access?

So this:

```
fileStatObject = os.stat( iDir + "/" + fileName )
accessTime = time.ctime( fileStatObject[stat.ST_ATIME] )
print accessTime
```

Results in this:
Tue Jun 23 16:06:04 2020

But what I need is this:
113

Comment: Either you did not paste your _real_ code or you do not use Python-3.x. `print accessTime` is illegal in Python-3.x. Please fix either the code or the tag. The answer may depend on the language version.

Comment: It's version 3.7, tags edited

Comment: As I said, `print accessTime` is illegal in Python-3.x. So, either your code is wrong or your tags are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't call `ctime` on it - that converts a timestamp to a string representation of the timestamp. Instead, you can find how much time has elapsed since that timestamp, and represent that in days:

```py
file_stat = os.stat(os.path.join(i_dir, file_name))
access_timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(file_stat[stat.ST_ATIME])
elapsed = datetime.datetime.now() - access_timestamp
print(f"File was accessed {elapsed.days} days ago")
```

You may wish to do further rounding of the elapsed time, but this should serve to illustrate how to more forward.

You should also be aware of timezone issues. You might need to use `utcnow()` instead of `now()`; I haven't addressed this issue in this answer.